# How can I calculate when a text corpus is representative of a language?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, representative

I am collecting and analyzing articles and other publications for building a text corpus.

I'd like to know how to calculate when my text corpus is representative of a field. That is, how many texts, and how long they should be.

I'd like to cover 99% of all researchers. And I will also use the corpus to obtain a list of concepts in the field (things like "cori cycle", TCA, or metabolomics). It would also be reassuring if I had covered 99% of them.

Neither will I be using it only to program a categorization algorithm, nor will its main use be a machine learning application. I expect to use it to extract some detailed information. For example, I'd like to produce a list of companies or researchers in a field, and would like to know what are my chances of having skipped some of them.

It is about a biochemistry subfield, but I assume a solution can be generalized to all types of texts.

Intuitively, I was thinking that maybe I should just stop collecting texts after I couldn't extract any new item from n texts. But how big should this n be?

Comment: You will need to be clearer about what information you want to extract from the corpus. What is the distribution you expect? How uncommon would you want a researcher to be before you had a <what percentage> chance of missing them?

Comment: @gung: question edited.

Comment: What you really need is a statement like, 'I want to have at least a 95% chance of including any researcher who accounts for at least 1% of the literature'. Regarding your statement, "I'd like to cover 99% of all researchers", imagine every researcher has contributed exactly 1 article. Then w/ N researchers there are N articles in the population. If N=100, you would need 99, but if N=1k, you need 990, etc. Is there any estimate of the total population size?

Comment: @gung: there is no estimate of the number of texts. And it keeps increasing every day.

Comment: @gung: the distribution of text/author is also unknown.

Answer (score 0):

***** Can't comment because of reputation so the Answer :) ********

Based on what I could understand you are more interested in the specific keywords related to the field & specific names of the field than common vocabulary. Since there is no reference to go by you can only keep sparse words from each new document. 
If after say 1000 (don't have reference for better ball park figure) documents all the new sparse words (present only in new documents or less than say 1% documents) are Company &/ Researcher names then it is safe to say that your corpus is at least representing most of the scientific vocabulary of the field.

Let me know if this makes sense.